# Circle in the legend handle doesn't work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and my matplotlib version is `2.1.1`. I am trying to plot a circular patch as a figure legend handle. [This example](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) gives a way of using customized handles like this:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

But I want a circular handle instead of a rectangular patch. So I tried:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
circle = mpatches.Circle(xy = (0.5, 0.5), radius = 100,color = "green")

ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

fig.legend(handles = [circle], labels = ["some funny label"])
plt.show()
```

However, I still get a rectangular patch, and in my opinion, in a wrong location. What exactly am I missing?

[image]

*Edit* : I am specifically asking what is wrong with my code. It is helpful to have workarounds but I don't see anything wrong with the code above.

Comment: Specifically, the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098362/using-mpatches-patch-for-a-custom-legend/44098900#44098900). Also, in the second example you are using `fig.legend` rather than `plt.legend`

Comment: @DavidG This is helpful but doesn't directly answer my question: what is wrong with my code?

Comment: It's because not all artists can be added to the legend using `plt.legend(handles=)`. Seems that a circle patch is one of them, so a more detailed approach must be used. The [legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) is a good read, and [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler) specific part too

Comment: Hmm. I actually saw this before posting but couldn't understand several things: what are those two classes doing? Why do they derive from `object`? What is a `handlebox`, and so on. Could you simplify these a bit for me?

Comment: You need to implement a custom handler, see https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-custom-legends-py) they do this as follows:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_circle = Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='Circle',
                        markerfacecolor='r', markersize=15),
plt.legend(handles=red_circle)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that Line2D has no `hatch` argument. So a Patch-like solution as requested in the question is still missing :/