# How to have patterns for the color bar in Biokit/corrplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wonder if it is possible with  corrplot (from the biokit package) to have a colobar with patterns.
In this example below, for the colobar, I would like to have 5 bubbles with differents sizes associated to the matrix's values ([-1, -0.5, 0, +0.5, +1]).

Ideas ?
thanks a lot

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from biokit.viz import corrplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import string

letters = string.ascii_uppercase[0:15]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(( (k, np.random.random(10)+ord(k)-65) for k in letters)))
df = df.corr()

c = corrplot.Corrplot(df)

c.plot(colorbar=True, upper='circle', rotation=60, cmap='Oranges', fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you know why in this case isn't chosen for a colormap without a light color at its center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding filled shapes to a colorbar seems not to be part of the standard interface. However, a legend could serve your goals. Some shapes are supported directly by the legend, others need a special handler, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098362/using-mpatches-patch-for-a-custom-legend/44098900#44098900).

It seems first some circles need to be created, for which color etc. can be set.
To tell the handler which shape exactly is meant, I'm misusing the label parameter.
From the [source of biokit's `corrplot`](https://github.com/biokit/biokit/blob/master/biokit/viz/corrplot.py), we learn that the ellipse is rotated either `+` or `-45°`, and that it is scaled by the absolute value of the correlation.

The following code puts everything together. The colorbar is drawn as a reference, but can be left out once everything is checked. The legend is positioned outside the main plot via `bbox_to_anchor=(x, y)`. These coordinates are in [axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). The ideal location depends on the size of the other elements, so some experimentation could be useful. I didn't draw the `corrplot` itself, as I don't have it installed, but you can replace the dummy scatter plot with it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
import matplotlib as mpl

class HandlerEllipse(mpl.legend_handler.HandlerPatch):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        d = float(orig_handle.get_label())
        center = 0.5 * width - 0.5 * xdescent, 0.5 * height - 0.5 * ydescent
        radius = (height + ydescent) * 1.8
        p = Ellipse(xy=center, width=radius, height=radius * (1 - abs(d)), angle=45 if d > 0 else -45)
        self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
        p.set_transform(trans)
        return [p]

#values = [1, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -1]
values = [1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5, -0.75, -1]

cmap = plt.cm.Oranges  # or plt.cm.PiYG
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter([0,1], [0,1], c=[-1,1], cmap=cmap, norm=norm)  # a dummy plot as a stand-in for the corrplot
char = plt.colorbar(ticks=values)

shapes = [Circle((0.5, 0.5), 1, facecolor=cmap(norm(d)), edgecolor='k', alpha=1, zorder=2, linewidth=1, label=d)
          for d in values]
plt.legend(handles=shapes, labels=values, title='Correlation', framealpha=1,
           bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1), loc='upper left',
           handler_map={Circle: HandlerEllipse()})
plt.tight_layout() # make sure legend and colorbar fit nicely in the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting legend]