# Is there any python equivalent of get_map function in R?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, ggplot2

I need to plot the map of a country (it may be any country according to the requirement) without specifying llcrnrlat,urcrnrlat,llcrnrlon and urcrnrlon.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Basemap without specifying the projection and coordinates of the map to read a shapefile. One can e.g. take the shapes of the countries from [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).

Example for a map of Switzerland:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

m = Basemap()

fn = r"ne_10m_admin_0_countries\ne_10m_admin_0_countries"
m.readshapefile(fn, 'shf', drawbounds = False)

def draw_country(country, ax=None,**kwargs):
    if ax == None: ax=plt.gca()
    for info, shape in zip(m.shf_info, m.shf):
        if info['NAME'] == country:
            s = np.array(shape)
            ax.plot(s[:,0], s[:,1], alpha=0)
            p= Polygon(s, **kwargs)
            ax.add_artist(p)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
draw_country("Switzerland",fill=True, facecolor= "crimson", edgecolor='none', alpha=0.7)
# try with other contries like 'Ireland', "Venezuela" etc
plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback is of course that when not specifying the projection, the country shape may not be what we're used to from usual maps.

For plotting countries on a map with a legend, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639981/how-to-show-shapefile-label-in-python-basemap-legend).